# How to deploy a single instance mongodb with persistant volume using NFS

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, docker-compose, persistent-storage

I have a microservice that is working on my laptop. However, I am using docker compose. I am working to deploy to a kubernetes cluster which I have already set up. I am stuck on making data persistent. E.g here is my mongodb in docker-compose

```
systemdb:
    container_name: system-db
    image: mongo:4.4.1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '9000:27017'
    volumes:
      - ./system_db:/data/db
    networks:
      - backend
```

Since it is an on premise solution, I went with an NFS server. I have created a Persistent Volume and Persistent Volume Claim (pvc-nfs-pv1) which seem to work well when testing with nginx. However, I don't know how to deploy a mongodb statefulset to use the pvc. I am not implementing a replicaset.

Here is my yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongod
spec:
  serviceName: mongodb-service
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: mongo
        environment: test
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: mongod-container
          image: mongo
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "0.2"
              memory: 200Mi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: pvc-nfs-pv1
              mountPath: /data/db
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: pvc-nfs-pv1
       annotations:
         volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "standard"
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 500Mi
```

How do i do it?

Answer (score 1):

`volumeClaimTemplates` are used for dynamic volume provisioning. So you're defining one volume claim template which will be used to create a `PersistentVolumeClaim` for each pod.

> The `volumeClaimTemplates` will provide stable storage using
> [PersistentVolumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)
> provisioned by a PersistentVolume Provisioner

So for  your use case you would need to create `storageclass` with nfs provisioner. [NFS Subdir external provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner)  is an automatic provisioner that use your *existing and already configured* NFS server to support dynamic provisioning of Kubernetes Persistent Volumes via Persistent Volume Claims. Persistent volumes are provisioned as `${namespace}-${pvcName}-${pvName}`.

Here`s an example how to define storage class:

```yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: managed-nfs-storage
provisioner: fuseim.pri/ifs # or choose another name, must match deployment's env PROVISIONER_NAME'
parameters:
  pathPattern: "${.PVC.namespace}/${.PVC.annotations.nfs.io/storage-path}" # waits for nfs.io/storage-path annotation, if not specified will accept as empty string.
  onDelete: delete
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have a solution. It works simply by selecting the volume by using the matchLabels selector.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mongodb-data-volume
  labels:
    app: moderetic
    type: mongodb
    role: data
spec:
  storageClassName: hcloud-volumes
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  csi:
    volumeHandle: "11099996"
    driver: csi.hetzner.cloud
    fsType: ext4

---

---
apiVersion: mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com/v1
kind: MongoDBCommunity
metadata:
  name: system-mongodb
  labels:
    app: moderetic
    type: mongodb
spec:
  members: 1
  type: ReplicaSet
  version: "4.2.6"
  logLevel: INFO
  security:
    authentication:
      modes: ["SCRAM"]
  users:
    - name: moderetic
      db: moderetic
      passwordSecretRef:
        name: mongodb-secret
      roles:
        - name: clusterAdmin
          db: moderetic
        - name: userAdminAnyDatabase
          db: moderetic
      scramCredentialsSecretName: moderetic-scram-secret
  additionalMongodConfig:
    storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.journalCompressor: zlib
  persistent: true
  statefulSet:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: mongod
              resources:
                requests:
                  cpu: 1
                  memory: 1Gi
                limits:
                  memory: 8Gi
            - name: mongodb-agent
              resources:
                requests:
                  memory: 50Mi
                limits:
                  cpu: 500m
                  memory: 256Mi
      volumeClaimTemplates:
        - metadata:
            name: data-volume
          spec:
            accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
            storageClassName: hcloud-volumes
            resources:
              requests:
                storage: 10Gi
            selector:
              matchLabels:
                app: moderetic
                type: mongodb
                role: data
        - metadata:
            name: logs-volume
          spec:
            accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
            storageClassName: hcloud-volumes
            resources:
              requests:
                storage: 10Gi
            selector:
              matchLabels:
                app: moderetic
                type: mongodb
                role: logs
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is how the mongo StatefulSet is going to use the pvc u have created ? By default It **wont** . It will create numbers of new pvc (depending of number of replicaset)  automatically  via the volumeClaimTemplates and it will be named like so : pvc-nfs-pv1-mongod-0 , pvc-nfs-pv1-mongod-1 etc ..
So if you want to use the pvc you created change the name to match  pvc-nfs-pv1-mongod-0
something like this

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  labels:
    role: mongo
  name: pvc-nfs-pv1-mongod-0
  namespace: default
spec:
...
  volumeName: nfs-pv1
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 500Mi
...
```

However I dont recommend using this method (issue: when you have many other replicasets .. do you have to create all the pvcs manually and the correspondent pv ).. Here is similar questions is asked in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64386094/kubernetes-statefulset-with-nfs-persistent-volume) and also in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43913441/kubernetes-nfs-with-statefulsets) , I recommend using **Dynamic NFS Provisioning**.

Hope I helped

Answer (score 0):

I do not use NFS but volumes at hetzner.com where my dev server is running. But I have exactly the same problem: As it is my dev system I destroy and rebuild it regularly. And by doing so I want the data on my volumes survive the deletion of the whole cluster. And when I rebuild it, all the volumes shall be mounted to the right pod.

For my postgres this works just fine. But using the mongodb kubernetes operator I am not able to get this running. The one mongodb pod stays forever in the state "Pending" because the PVC I created and bound manually to the volume is already bound to a volume. Or so it seems to me.

I am thankful for any help,
Tobias

The exact message I can see is:

```
0/1 nodes are available: 1 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
```

PVC and PV:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: data-volume-system-mongodb-0
  labels:
    app: moderetic
    type: mongodb
spec:
  storageClassName: hcloud-volumes
  volumeName: mongodb-data-volume
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mongodb-data-volume
  labels:
    app: moderetic
    type: mongodb
spec:
  storageClassName: hcloud-volumes
  claimRef:
    name: data-volume-system-mongodb-0
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  csi:
    volumeHandle: "11099996"
    driver: csi.hetzner.cloud
    fsType: ext4
```

And the mongodb StatefulSet:

```
apiVersion: mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com/v1
kind: MongoDBCommunity
metadata:
  name: system-mongodb
  labels:
    app: moderetic
    type: mongodb
spec:
  members: 1
  type: ReplicaSet
  version: "4.2.6"
  security:
    authentication:
      modes: ["SCRAM"]
  users:
    - name: moderetic
      db: moderetic
      passwordSecretRef:
        name: mongodb-secret
      roles:
        - name: clusterAdmin
          db: moderetic
        - name: userAdminAnyDatabase
          db: moderetic
      scramCredentialsSecretName: moderetic-scram-secret
  additionalMongodConfig:
    storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.journalCompressor: zlib
  persistent: true
  statefulSet:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: mongod
              resources:
                requests:
                  cpu: 1
                  memory: 1Gi
                limits:
                  memory: 8Gi
            - name: mongodb-agent
              resources:
                requests:
                  memory: 50Mi
                limits:
                  cpu: 500m
                  memory: 256Mi
      volumeClaimTemplates:
        - metadata:
            name: data-volume
          spec:
            accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
            storageClassName: hcloud-volumes
            resources:
              requests:
                storage: 10Gi
        - metadata:
            name: logs-volume
          spec:
            accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
            storageClassName: hcloud-volumes
            resources:
              requests:
                storage: 10Gi
```